# Xamarin.iOS binding project works on an iPhone emulator but not on a real iPhone device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Why does my Xamarin.iOS binding project work on an iPhone emulator but not on a real iPhone?

Source: https://github.com/Toine-db/pocketsphinx-xamarin-ios-demo/tree/sharpie-tryout/src
Using fat libraries: https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx/tree/master/Sphinx/lib

For a project I need to use two fat iOS libraries (*.a) to be able to use a 3rd party recognition system PocketSphinx.
With Sharpie I managed to get things up and running, and every method I need to use from the library is working on the emulator. When I try to use the exact same code on a real iPhone 6S with iOS 13.6.1 I get exceptions or errors on the first methods I need to use.

*First method (crash):*
[ViewController.FreeDecoderResources()](https://github.com/Toine-db/pocketsphinx-xamarin-ios-demo/blob/sharpie-tryout/src/pocketsphinxios/ViewController.cs#L328) invokes  pocketsphinxiosbinding.CFunctions.cmd_ln_free();
error: Method idx 0 is greater than number of rows (0) in PPDB MethodDebugInformation table, for method pocketsphinxiosbinding.CFunctions:cmd_ln_free

*Second method (error):*
[ViewController.InitDecoder()](https://github.com/Toine-db/pocketsphinx-xamarin-ios-demo/blob/sharpie-tryout/src/pocketsphinxios/ViewController.cs#L81) invokes  ... = pocketsphinxiosbinding.CFunctions.cmd_ln_init(……)
error: Number of arguments must be even.
(this is PocketSphinx telling the arguments are not correct received)
this error is coming from:
[source fat library](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/blob/4ffc4b79515fd18f7adfbf80c20f3c0ecb9edccd/src/libsphinxbase/util/cmd_ln.c#L709)

Can it be that Xamarin invokes .a (ios libraries) methods differently on a real device, compared to an emulator?

The two use *.a libraries are fat Libraries for (armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64, arm64)
The real iPhone is a 6s, I think its using the arm64

Anyone any experience with binding fat libraries?

Comment: Did you check if you are using the "Release" version of the fat libraries and not the "Debug" one?

Comment: @pinedax don't know if its release or debug, should it matter? because they both should contain the same public methods..dont they? 
there is only 1 version available of the fat libs: https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx/tree/master/Sphinx/lib